# Google charts change table if only one type of value

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, google-visualization

i have a issue with google charts
I want to have ColumnChart when have multiple (more than one) types of data, and change it to PieChart when have only one value
This is my code:

this is how i get the data:

```
var <?php echo $divName;?>_data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

how I(now) set the PieChart:

```
var <?php echo $divName;?>_chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $divName;?>'));
```

and for ColumnChart:

```
var <?php echo $divName;?>_chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('<?php echo $divName;?>'));
```

and the echo the chart

```
<?php echo $divName;?>_chart.draw(<?php echo $divName;?>_data
```

I know it should be a simple `if (<?php echo $divName;?>_chart) < 2types then draw PieChart` but i don't know how to get the information about how many types have the DataTable 
Can someone help me? I'll be very grateful

Comment: `console.log()` your datatable object, see if you can understand something from this output

Comment: @u_mulder the simple ways is the best :D and yes after I go to the console it worked: the Nf were the objects -  ' if (<?php echo $divName;?>_data.Nf.length < 2 ) {' and it worked, thanks!